# How do static fields in C++ struct are set during template specialization?

Tags: c++, g++

Considering the following code for a C++ struct `type_no`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i>
struct type_no {
  static const int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct type_no<1> {
  static const bool value = 10;
};

template<>
struct type_no<2> {
  static const bool value = 20;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << type_no<0>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << type_no<1>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << type_no<2>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I think that runing the above code should produces:

```
0
10
20
```

But after compiling the above code with `g++ -std=c++14 code.cc -o code`, running `./code` produces:

```
0
1
1
```

The OS is `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.14.12-x86_64-linode92 x86_64)`. The result of `g++ --version` is `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04) 6.3.0 20170519`.

Comment: `1` is the largest value you can store in a `bool`. Did you mean to have `int`s in the specializations too?

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant parts of the Standard:

> **6.9.1**
>   Values of type bool are either `true` or `false`.
>
> **7.14 Boolean conversions [[conv.bool]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/conv.bool)**
>   1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`. For direct-initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.